# error while cross-compiling for arm architecture

Tags: compiler-errors, linux-kernel, arm, driver, cross-compiling

I am running linux OS on my system. I have cross compiled linux kernel 4.9.11 for arm arch successfully, now I am trying to cross compile a wifi driver for arm architecture on x86 platform.
I have set both `ARCH=arm` & `CROSS_COMPILE=<path to toolchain>` env & passing the `KERNEL DIRECTORY = cross compiled kernel directory`. Even after specifying the ARCH, x86 files are being referred. I am getting following error. Can anyone point me if I am missing something. Because of character restrictions I am updating only half log.

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=~/imx/boot/gcc-linaro-6.4.1-2017.11-i686_arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- KERNELDIR=~/linux-stable/

Build drivers
cd /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers && make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE=
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers'
/bin/sh: 1: [: -gt: argument expected
make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.9.11+/build SUBDIRS=/home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new clean
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/wlan-3/linux-stable'
  CLEAN   /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/.tmp_versions
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/wlan-3/linux-stable'
make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.9.11+/build SUBDIRS=/home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS=/Module.symvers modules  WLAN_ROOT=/home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/"qcacld-new" MODNAME=wlan CONFIG_QCA_WIFI_ISOC=0 CONFIG_QCA_WIFI_2_0=1 CONFIG_QCA_CLD_WLAN=m WLAN_OPEN_SOURCE=1 CONFIG_CLD_HL_SDIO_CORE=y CONFIG_LINUX_QCMBR=y  
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/wlan-3/linux-stable'
  LD      /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.o
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/bitops.h:16:0,
                 from ./include/linux/bitops.h:36,
                 from ./include/linux/kernel.h:10,
                 from ./include/linux/list.h:8,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:9,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/inc/wlan_hdd_includes.h:48,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.c:50:
./arch/x86/include/asm/arch_hweight.h: In function ‘__arch_hweight64’:
./arch/x86/include/asm/arch_hweight.h:54:42: error: expected ‘:’ or ‘)’ before ‘POPCNT64’
  asm (ALTERNATIVE("call __sw_hweight64", POPCNT64, X86_FEATURE_POPCNT)
                                          ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h:132:28: note: in definition of macro ‘ALTINSTR_REPLACEMENT’
  b_replacement(num)":\n\t" newinstr "\n" e_replacement(num) ":\n\t"
                            ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/arch_hweight.h:54:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘ALTERNATIVE’
  asm (ALTERNATIVE("call __sw_hweight64", POPCNT64, X86_FEATURE_POPCNT)
       ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h:268:0,
                 from ./include/linux/atomic.h:4,
                 from ./include/linux/jump_label.h:169,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/string_64.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/string.h:4,
                 from ./include/linux/string.h:18,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/page_32.h:34,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/page.h:13,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:58,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/inc/wlan_hdd_includes.h:48,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.c:50:
./arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h: At top level:
./arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:19:40: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’
 static inline long atomic64_read(const atomic64_t *v)
                                        ^
In file included from ./include/uapi/linux/stddef.h:1:0,
                 from ./include/linux/stddef.h:4,
                 from ./include/uapi/linux/posix_types.h:4,
                 from ./include/uapi/linux/types.h:13,
                 from ./include/linux/types.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/list.h:4,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:9,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/inc/wlan_hdd_includes.h:48,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.c:50:
./arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h: In function ‘atomic64_read’:
./arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:21:22: error: request for member ‘counter’ in something not a structure or union
  return READ_ONCE((v)->counter);
                      ^
./include/linux/compiler.h:305:17: note: in definition of macro ‘__READ_ONCE’
  union { typeof(x) __val; char __c[1]; } __u;   \
                 ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:21:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘READ_ONCE’
  return READ_ONCE((v)->counter);
         ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:21:22: error: request for member ‘counter’ in something not a structure or union
  return READ_ONCE((v)->counter);
                      ^
./include/linux/compiler.h:307:22: note: in definition of macro ‘__READ_ONCE’
   __read_once_size(&(x), __u.__c, sizeof(x));  \
                      ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:21:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘READ_ONCE’
  return READ_ONCE((v)->counter);
         ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:21:22: error: request for member ‘counter’ in something not a structure or union
  return READ_ONCE((v)->counter);
                      ^
./include/linux/compiler.h:307:42: note: in definition of macro ‘__READ_ONCE’
   __read_once_size(&(x), __u.__c, sizeof(x));  \
                                          ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:21:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘READ_ONCE’
  return READ_ONCE((v)->counter);
         ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:21:22: error: request for member ‘counter’ in something not a structure or union
  return READ_ONCE((v)->counter);
                      ^
./include/linux/compiler.h:309:30: note: in definition of macro ‘__READ_ONCE’
   __read_once_size_nocheck(&(x), __u.__c, sizeof(x)); \
                              ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:21:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘READ_ONCE’
  return READ_ONCE((v)->counter);
         ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:21:22: error: request for member ‘counter’ in something not a structure or union
  return READ_ONCE((v)->counter);
                      ^
./include/linux/compiler.h:309:50: note: in definition of macro ‘__READ_ONCE’
   __read_once_size_nocheck(&(x), __u.__c, sizeof(x)); \
                                                  ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:21:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘READ_ONCE’
  return READ_ONCE((v)->counter);
In file included from ./include/linux/jump_label.h:169:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/string_64.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/string.h:4,
                 from ./include/linux/string.h:18,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/page_32.h:34,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/page.h:13,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:58,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/inc/wlan_hdd_includes.h:48,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.c:50:
./include/linux/atomic.h:1000:49: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’
 static inline void atomic64_andnot(long long i, atomic64_t *v)
                                                 ^
./include/linux/atomic.h:1005:60: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’
 static inline long long atomic64_fetch_andnot(long long i, atomic64_t *v)
                                                            ^
./include/linux/atomic.h:1010:68: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’
 static inline long long atomic64_fetch_andnot_relaxed(long long i, atomic64_t *v)
                                                                    ^
./include/linux/atomic.h:1015:68: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’
 static inline long long atomic64_fetch_andnot_acquire(long long i, atomic64_t *v)
                                                                    ^
./include/linux/atomic.h:1020:68: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’
 static inline long long atomic64_fetch_andnot_release(long long i, atomic64_t *v)
                                                                    ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h:288:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:18,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:52,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:58,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/inc/wlan_hdd_includes.h:48,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.c:50:
./include/asm-generic/pgtable-nopud.h:15:0: error: "PUD_SHIFT" redefined [-Werror]
 #define PUD_SHIFT PGDIR_SHIFT
 ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h:240:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:18,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:52,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:58,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/inc/wlan_hdd_includes.h:48,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.c:50:
./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_64_types.h:34:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PUD_SHIFT 30
 ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h:288:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:18,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:52,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:58,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/inc/wlan_hdd_includes.h:48,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.c:50:
./include/asm-generic/pgtable-nopud.h:16:0: error: "PTRS_PER_PUD" redefined [-Werror]
 #define PTRS_PER_PUD 1
 ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h:240:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:18,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:52,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:58,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/inc/wlan_hdd_includes.h:48,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.c:50:
./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_64_types.h:35:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PTRS_PER_PUD 512
 ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h:288:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:18,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:52,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:58,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/inc/wlan_hdd_includes.h:48,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.c:50:
./include/asm-generic/pgtable-nopud.h:17:0: error: "PUD_SIZE" redefined [-Werror]
 #define PUD_SIZE   (1UL << PUD_SHIFT)
 ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h:240:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:18,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:52,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:58,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/inc/wlan_hdd_includes.h:48,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.c:50:
./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_64_types.h:51:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PUD_SIZE (_AC(1, UL) << PUD_SHIFT)
 ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h:288:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:18,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:52,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:58,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/inc/wlan_hdd_includes.h:48,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.c:50:
./include/asm-generic/pgtable-nopud.h:18:0: error: "PUD_MASK" redefined [-Werror]
 #define PUD_MASK   (~(PUD_SIZE-1))
 ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h:240:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:18,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:52,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:58,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/inc/wlan_hdd_includes.h:48,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.c:50:
./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_64_types.h:52:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PUD_MASK (~(PUD_SIZE - 1))
 ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h:309:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:18,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:52,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:58,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/inc/wlan_hdd_includes.h:48,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.c:50:
./include/asm-generic/pgtable-nopmd.h:19:0: error: "PMD_SHIFT" redefined [-Werror]
 #define PMD_SHIFT PUD_SHIFT
 ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h:240:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:18,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:52,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:58,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/inc/wlan_hdd_includes.h:48,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.c:50:
./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_64_types.h:41:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PMD_SHIFT 21
 ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h:309:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:18,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:52,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:58,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/inc/wlan_hdd_includes.h:48,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.c:50:
./include/asm-generic/pgtable-nopmd.h:20:0: error: "PTRS_PER_PMD" redefined [-Werror]
 #define PTRS_PER_PMD 1
 ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h:240:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:18,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:52,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:58,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/inc/wlan_hdd_includes.h:48,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.c:50:
./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_64_types.h:42:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PTRS_PER_PMD 512
 ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h:309:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:18,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:52,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:58,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/inc/wlan_hdd_includes.h:48,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.c:50:
./include/asm-generic/pgtable-nopmd.h:21:0: error: "PMD_SIZE" redefined [-Werror]
 #define PMD_SIZE   (1UL << PMD_SHIFT)
 ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h:240:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:18,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:52,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:58,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/inc/wlan_hdd_includes.h:48,
                 from /home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.c:50:
./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_64_types.h:49:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PMD_SIZE (_AC(1, UL) << PMD_SHIFT)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing that particular WiFi driver from loadable module to built-in module in kernel config?

Comment: @arshan I need to compile it as loadable module only. requirement demands it to be loadable

Comment: As in log, 


"make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.9.11+/build SUBDIRS=/home/wlan-3/qca/qca9377-le-2-3-3_qca_oem.git/wlan_host/cnss_proc/fixce/AIO/build/../drivers/qcacld-new clean"




wifi driver is being compiled with "ARCH=i386". Does Makefile in wifi driver code hard code it? How are you making sure make arguments you are passing is actually going down to drivers make ?

Comment: Check the log, it says make `ARCH=i386`. Just set environment variables `export ARCH=arm` and `export CROSS_COMPILE=<toolchain/path/>` and re-try.

Comment: I feel There is some issue in Makefile can you add snippet or full Makefile which is used here?

Comment: $ make FOO=test
echo test
test
$ cat Makefile 

all:
 echo $(FOO)

Comment: SOLVED : as everyone suggested, one of the Makefile was setting X86 flags. Thankyou all.

Answer (score 1):

following is my output and make file which worked
so can you please post Makefile or make changes likewise.

```
$ make FOO=test
echo test
test
$ cat Makefile 

all:
    echo $(FOO)
```

OR in case you do't want to share as it is propitiatory then alternatively can try this add new entry in makefile say test
like

```
test:
    echo $(ARCH) $(CROSS_COMPILE)
```

and then use

```
$ make test ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/test
```